# How to move mails to another folder in the POP3 account from the inbox?

Tags: email, pop3

I have a WCF application which reads mails from a pop3 account and deletes them from the inbox after reading it by sending "DELE 1". Now i want to do some change in this functionality. ie instead of deleting the mail from the inbox i want to move it to another folder.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The POP protocol doesn't have a folder level concept. So you won't be able to move messages between folders using the POP protocol.

You can view information about POP here and the RFC links will take you to the detailed specification documents for each version and extension of the protocol.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol

The IMAP protocol is a newer protocol for managing a mailbox, IMAP does support the folder concept, so I would look there.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol

With IMAP you will be able to accomplish moving messages between folders on the mail server.